# vscode remote container error when adding dev configuration files

Tags: vscode-devcontainer, remote-development

[120279 ms] Dev Containers 0.288.0 in VS Code 1.77.2 (e344f1f539a80912a0e9357cec841f36ce97a4e2).

[120278 ms]  -- CREATEDEVCONTAINER v2

[229437 ms]  -- CREATEDEVCONTAINER v2

[235168 ms] Start: Run: C:\Users<...>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node c:\Users<...>.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.288.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js templates apply --workspace-folder C:\Users<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-output-dir-1681390621207 --template-id ghcr.io/devcontainers/templates/alpine:latest --template-args {"imageVariant":"3.17"} --features [] --tmp-dir C:\Users<...>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-dir-1681390621207

[235493 ms] [2023-04-13T12:57:01.545Z] @devcontainers/cli 0.35.0. Node.js v16.14.2. win32 10.0.22621 x64.

[235689 ms] [2023-04-13T12:57:01.741Z] **Failed to parse JSON with mimeType 'application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json'**:

[235690 ms] [2023-04-13T12:57:01.741Z] Failed to fetch template manifest for ghcr.io/devcontainers/templates/alpine:latest

[235691 ms] [2023-04-13T12:57:01.741Z] Failed to fetch template 'ghcr.io/devcontainers/templates/alpine:latest'.

[235702 ms] Exit code 1

---

Windows 11

1: Docker (v20.10.24)

2: vscode (1.77.2)

3: Installed vscode extension ([remote development](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack))

4: Tried to perform "Add dev configuration files..."

Comment: This occurred for me when my computer's VPN connection to our package repository dropped. Reconnecting to the VPN fixed it.